# printing user inputted array info

Tags: arrays, printing

i read about a few ways to print arrays but no matter how i try it i get jibberish printed out. can someone tell me what's going on behind the scenes here? thanks in advance!

and this is the output i get.   [[I@1520a9d6]

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class intarray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number other than zero, then hit enter. Do this five times.");

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array=new int[5];


       int one=input1.nextInt();
       array[0]=one;
       int two=input2.nextInt();
       array[1]=two;
       int three=input3.nextInt();
       array[2]=three;
       int four=input4.nextInt();
       array[3]=four;
       int five=input5.nextInt();
       array[4]=five;


       input1.close();
       input2.close();
       input3.close();
       input4.close();
       input5.close();

    System.out.print(Arrays.asList(array));
```

}
}

Comment: Why do you have *five* Scanners? You should only need one, and call `nextInt()` five times.

Comment: wasnt completely sure it wouldnt do some craziness so i went safe and used 5. i see how it works now, thanks for the clarification. i still dont understand my output jibberish though.

Comment: Try just doing `System.out.print(array);` first. If that works, then try to do `ArrayList<Integer> test = Arrays.asList(array); System.out.print(test.toString());` My guess is that Java is printing out the memory location of the list instead of its contents so you get that weird output.

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> gives me an error that it cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: this worked...System.out.print(array[0] + ", ");
     System.out.print(array[1] + ", ");
     System.out.print(array[2] + ", ");
     System.out.print(array[3] + ", ");
     System.out.print(array[4] + ".");